# I want to upload some picture files to my server and record the file name in mysql database but somehow there exists a problem

Tags: php, mysql, server, upload

I want to upload some picture files to my server and record the file name in mysql database but somehow there exists a problem. Anyone can help.
Below is the error message:

File is an image - image/jpeg.
Warning: move_uploaded_file( ../uploads/2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/all/upload.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpSqx5eG' to ' ../uploads/2.jpg' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/all/upload.php on line 43
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

```
    $target_dir = "../uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
       && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Did you give the "uploads" directory the correct permission?

Comment: What is the exact value of `$target_file` immediately before you use `move_uploaded_file()`?

Comment: "Permission denied" seems pretty clear. Check whether the account under which your PHP code is running has permission to write to the relevant folder(s). (If you're using Apache as the webserver then the account will most likely be the account under which Apache is running). Also, double-check that the filename and path you're specifying is actually correct.

Comment: as I am using macbook...my upload file is in "/Library/WebServer/Documents/all/uploads"...and how to check with the permission? i am sure that the upload folder which can be written or read by everyone

Comment: i donot use the Apache...what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than likely you are point the file to save in a folder that does not exist
Try changing the  `$target_dir = "uploads/";` to  `$target_dir = "../uploads/";`

Comment: Good idea, but there's a typo in `$target_dir = ../"uploads/";`

Comment: Now you only need to explain why you think the uploads directory is located in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`.

Comment: i have amended the code from $target_dir = "uploads/"; to  $target_dir = "../uploads/";...but the problem still exists

Comment: Have you tried checking the permissions on the folder ?

Comment: yes, i have checked the permissions....now the error shows File is an image - image/jpeg.
Warning: move_uploaded_file( ../uploads/2.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/all/upload.php on line 43

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phpSqx5eG' to ' ../uploads/2.jpg' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/all/upload.php on line 43
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.

Comment: It seems to be the same error,
1. Check if you have /Library/WebServer/Documents/all/uploads folder in your directory
2. Check that you changes the code to $target_dir = "../uploads/";
Make sure you actually created the folder